# JQuery - Highlight current tab in navigation

Tags: jquery

I have seen numerous ways to highlight the current tab, but they all have been with separate html pages where as I am not using different pages such as about.html, services.html etc.

I am currently using divs with the information I need, and whenever I click the 'about' tab a div will show with the about information. But I'm not sure of a way to highlight the tab.

Here is what I have as the html in the body:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul><li><a href="Javascript:ShowContent('about');
                 Javascript:HideContent('graph')"
                 class="about"></a></li>

    <div class="portfolio"><a class="portfolio"><span>Portfolio</span></a></div>

    <div class="accordionContent">
            <a href="Javascript:HideContent('about');
                     Javascript:ShowContent('graph')"
                class="graph"></a>
    </div>
</ul>
```

The menu uses background graphics so I want to replace the original graphic with another. Also, as you can see I am using a accordion menu too. I'm not sure how much it will effect end code but I thought I should include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".tabHeader").click(function() {
    $(".selectedHeader").removeClass("selectedHeader");
    $(this).addClass("selectedHeader");
    // Do your other stuff to show the correct tab.
});
```

Your css rules for .selectedHeader can change color, background-image, etc.

Comment: Although I really appreciate you posting the code, i am not entirely sure about how to show the correct tab. For instance I have one tab with the class of ".about", in what way would i replace that class. Also would that code replace all other classes to indicate that they are not activated with the appropriate div?

Comment: Use your existing HideContent and ShowContent functions.

Comment: After twiddling with the code for the last 15 or so mins, I finally got it going. I noticed that within the removeClass brackets that I didn't need to include the period before the class i.e. .class rather it would be just class. Thank you very much Dave, I really appreciate it.